# ReduxToolKit: correct way to use SelectFromResult options in a Query hook?

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am trying to understand how to correctly use SelectFromResult from the official documentation:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#selecting-data-from-a-query-result

I have extended the Pokemon example to retrieve a filtered list of Pokemons ending in "saur" using SelectFromResult but the output results in a loss of error and isLoading data

live sandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rtk-query-selectfromresult-vvb7l

relevant code here:

the endpoint extracts out the relevant data with a transformResponse:

```
    getAllPokemon: builder.query({
      query: () => `pokemon/`,
      transformResponse: (response: any) => {
        console.log("transformResponse", response);
        return response.results;
      }
    })
```

and the hook fails if i try to selectFromResult and I lose error and isLoading variables as they are no longer returned from the hook. If I comment out the SelectFromResult option they are then correctly returned.

```
export const PokemonList = () => {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetAllPokemonQuery(undefined, {
    selectFromResult: ({ data }) => ({
      data: data?.filter((item: Pokemon) => item.name.endsWith("saur"))
    })
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) console.log("filtered result", data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div>
      {data?.map((item: Pokemon) => (
        <p>{item.name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

My question: I dont want to lose fetch status when trying to filter results using the recommended method. How do I modify the above code to correctly SelectFromResult and maintain the correct error, isLoading, etc status values from the hook?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solution found:

I passed in and returned the additional required variables (and tested by adding a polling interval to allow me to disconnect to force and error)

```
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetAllPokemonQuery(undefined, {
    selectFromResult: ({ data, error, isLoading }) => ({
      data: data?.filter((item: Pokemon) => item.name.endsWith("saur")),
      error,
      isLoading
    }),
    pollingInterval: 3000,
  });
```

Comment: Correct. The purpose of `selectFromResult` is that you can also filter those away, for example if you are not interested in that information and want to reduce the amount of rerenders that would occur if those would change.

Comment: How to implement typescript in this?

Comment: thanks. was messing my head over this selectFromResult. This helped

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution for getting statuses: isLoading, isError , etc and necessary data via selectFromResult

```
  const { data, isSuccess, isError} = useGetAllEventsQuery(undefined, {
    selectFromResult: (result) => ({
      isSuccess: result?.isSuccess,
      isError: result?.isError,
      data:  result.data?.[0]
    }),
  });

  console.log(isSuccess, isError, data)
```